# Saving a vector as a single number?

Tags: c#, math

I was wondering if it would be possible to get a vector with an X and a Y value as a single number, knowing that both X and Y can range from -65000 to +65000.

Is this possible in any way?

Code examples on how to convert from this kind of number and to it would be nice.

Comment: do you have a class with two members X and Y and you want to save this info in a scalar value of whatever type?

Comment: are X and Y an integers?

Comment: Yes Davide, that's exactly what I want.

Snowbear, yes, they are integers.

Comment: Since -65k..65k requires 17 bits, you can't store both in another 32bit integer, you need 34 bits for the pair. But you could store them in the higher/lower part of a long if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in a `ulong`:

```
ulong rslt = (uint)x;
rslt = rslt << 32;
rslt |= ((uint)y);
```

To get it out:

```
int x = (int)(rslt >> 32);
int y = (int)(rslt & 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 1):

To combine:

```
var limit = 65000;
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
var single = x * (limit + 1) + y;
```

And then:

```
y = single % (limit + 1);
x = single - y / (limit + 1);
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/B6hwL)**.

Of course, you have to assume that the maximum value for `single` fits within the size of the data type that stores it (which in this case it does).

Comment: You'll have to divide `x` by `limit+1` in your reverse transformation.

Comment: +1 for the link to Ideone as well, that's indeed a cool site.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `X` and `Y` are both integer values and there is no overflow (32bit values is not enough) you can use e.g. (pseudocode)

```
V = fromXY(X, Y) = (y+65000)*130001+(x+65000)
(X,Y) = toXY(V) = (V%130001-65000,V/130001-65000)    // <= / is integer division
```

(`130001` is the number of distinct values for `X` or `Y`)

Answer (score -3):

the union does what you want very easily.
See also: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/

```
typedef long int64;
typedef int int32;

union {
    struct { int32 a, b; };
    int64 a_and_b;
} stacker;

int main ()
{
    stacker.a = -1000;
    stacker.b = 2000;
    cout << stacker.a << ", " << stacker.b << endl;
    cout << stacker.a_and_b << endl;
}
```

this will output:
-1000, 2000 <-- a and b read as two int32
8594229558296 <-- a and b interprested as a single int64

Comment: The question is tagged C#, not C++.

Comment: I don't understand that. I'd be great with C#.